# yii cgridview create dynamic column based on data from cell

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have a table with 4 columns.

id is ai pk

jobno is fk from jobs table

qty

biditems_id is fk from biditems

there can be many jobno

there can be many biditems_id

but each row can only exist once, so a jobno cannot have 2 of the same biditems_id.

I want to create a cgridview to show different types of biditems as separate columns. so in the cgridview i will have jobno, qty, biditems_id as type 1, biditems_id as type 2 etc.

A jobno can have many biditems with a qty.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet?

Comment: I havn't been able to think of an easy way to do it.